# How can I use an optional argument in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

In the following source code, optional arguments `txt` and `rtf` are not working properly.

The program must be able to take either `txt` or `rtf` as an argument, not both.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser


class MainClass:
    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        print("[Start of Main]")

        # initialize argument parser
        my_parser = ArgumentParser()
        my_parser.add_argument("-i", help="input directory", type=str)
        my_parser.add_argument("-o", help="output directory", type=str)
        my_parser.add_argument("--txt", help="output as .txt files")
        my_parser.add_argument("--rtf", help="output as .rtf files")

        # parse the argument
        args = my_parser.parse_args()

        if args.i is None:
            print("INPUT: current directory")
        else:
            print("INPUT: specific directory " + args.i)

        if args.o is None:
            print("OUTPUT: current directory")
        else:
            print("OUTPUT: specific directory " + args.o)

        if args.txt is not None and args.rtf is not None:
            print("Default output is .txt")
        elif args.txt is None and args.rtf is None:
            print("Default output is .txt")
        elif args.txt is not None:
            print(".txt output")
        elif args.rtf is not None:
            print(".rtf output")


        print("[End of Main]")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainClass.main()
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\pc\source\>python command_line_args_test.py -o "c:\\" --rtf
[Start of Main]
INPUT: current directory
OUTPUT: specific directory c:\ --rtf
Default output is .txt
[End of Main]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you are looking for `myArgGroup = my_parser.mutually_exclusive_group()` then just add `--txt` and `--rtf` as you normally would. i.e. `myArgGroup.add_argument("--txt")` & `myArgGroup.add_argument("--rtf")`.. Here's the documentation for you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion

Comment: What are the values of `args.rxt` and `args.rtf` in your example?

Comment: @mkrieger1, nothing. blank.

Comment: What do you get when you add `print(repr(args.txt), repr(args.rtf))`?

Comment: @mkrieger1, `C:\Users\pc\source\repos\lxml-to-dict-test>python command_line_args_test.py -o "c:\\" --rtf
[Start of Main]
usage: command_line_args_test.py [-h] [-i I] [-o O] [--txt TXT] [--rtf RTF]
command_line_args_test.py: error: argument --rtf: expected one argument
`

Comment: just look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion ... **will make sure that only one of the arguments in the mutually exclusive group was present on the command line**

Comment: However now I'm confused why you suddenly get a different output than what you have shown in the question.

Comment: In the `output` display it looks like `"c:\\" --rtf` is the whole argument for '-o', as though it was quoted.  In the comment, the 'expected one argument' error is what I expected.  You need to use `--rtf somename'.  I'd suggest getting the basic input working before trying to add the `mutually_exclusive` stuff.  Do a `print(args)` to get a clearer idea of what the parser does.